# Completely forget a single domain in Chrome

Tags: google-chrome, browser-history

How do I completely remove all data about a single domain in Google Chrome? (in one action)

Use case:

- I am developing an offline web application, and frequently need to 'start fresh' while testing
- Chrome's "Clear browsing data" can only be limited to time, not domains
- Removing a domain's pages in history does not remove service workers
- App Cache doesn't work properly in Chrome's Incognito mode

Ideally, a UI button or keyboard shortcut would be best. Extensions are fine, if they work.

Please don't submit answer unless service workers are also removed (I know there are many solutions for cookies/cache etc).

thanks

Answer (score 0):

Chrome now includes a 'Clear storage' function in the 'Application' tab of dev tools (using v52). Thanks Chrome!